# explaination for ner tags, expecially DEMONYM

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I tried CoreNLP NER with the following sentence from some corpus.
"匈牙利总统等外国政府首脑将访华"
And I expected to get tag GPE or LOCATION for 匈牙利, but I got tag "DEMONYM".
And I googled tag DEMONYM but found no help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak Chinese but if google translate is correct this translates to:

> Hungarian President and other foreign heads of government will visit China

In that case `DEMONYM` is a correct tag and not `LOCATION` i.e. "Hungarian" is the [demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) and "Hungary" the location.

Also google translate tells me that:

1. 匈牙利 = Hungary
2. 匈牙 = Hungarian

So (if you haven't) you may want to confirm the sentence segmentation as DEMONYM may refer to 匈牙 i.e. get a list of sentence segments and NER tags.

Excuse my lack of knowledge about Chinese grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it.